# Django URL (Page Not Found)

Tags: django, django-urls

Just starting out with Django and figuring out the URL dispatcher. From what I can see in the docs the following regular expression should catch `news/story/2012/10/23/this-is-my-first-story`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('news.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^news/story/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d){2}/(?P<day>\d){2}/(?P<title_key>\w+)/$', 'story'),
)
```

However, I am getting the following error...

> Using the URLconf defined in `mysite.urls`, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> - `^polls/`
> - `^news/`
> - `^$`
> - `^news/`
> - `^news/story/(?P<year>\d)/(?P<month>\d)/(?P<day>\d)/(?P<title_key>\d)/$`
> - `^admin/doc/`
> - `^admin/`
>
> The current URL, `news/story/2012/10/23/this-is-my-first-story`, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you're only accepting ONE digit per pattern. You need to modify it to `\d+` or more appropriately, `\d{4}` for `year` and `\d{2}` for `month` and `day`.

Second, the last pattern, for `title_key` is set to only accept numeric (`\d`), if you want a slug, you should use `[\w-]+`

Comment: thanks. I've updated it to... 

url(r'^news/story/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<title_key>\w+)/$', 'story')

still something is up :/

Comment: Not `\w+`. Use `[\w-]+`. Otherwise you won't catch the hyphens in the slug.

Comment: And also, the URL regex requires a trailing  **"/"**.
To match the example URL one must either remove the trailing "/" from the URL regex, or make it optional: 'url-regex-goes-here/?$'

Comment: @BorisChervenkov: That's incorrect. Django's default behavior is to redirect URLs not ending in a slash to a version ending in a slash. It will work just fine without an `?`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: You're right about the default behavior, but I wouldn't call the suggestion "incorrect". Default behavior does not mean everybody keeps this setting enabled for a number of reasons.